# Apache pulsar 2.8.0 standalone failing

Tags: java, admin, pulsar

Pulsar standalone do not start and i get such error.

Maybe someone knows how to fix it?

What I noticed, it happens when i turn off my pc and turn it on after night and try to start pulsar standalone.

Also I have set retention for one of my namespaces. Till then I did not noticed this problem.

To start pulsar i need delete all data folder, after that it starts.

```
10:56:47.858 [main] ERROR org.apache.pulsar.functions.worker.PulsarWorkerService - Error Starting up in worker
org.apache.pulsar.client.admin.PulsarAdminException: java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: org.apache.pulsar.client.admin.internal.http.AsyncHttpConnector$RetryException: Could not complete the operation. Number of retries has been exhausted. Failed reason: Maximum redirect reached: 5
    at org.apache.pulsar.client.admin.internal.BaseResource.getApiException(BaseResource.java:247) ~[org.apache.pulsar-pulsar-client-admin-original-2.8.0.jar:2.8.0]
    at org.apache.pulsar.client.admin.internal.BaseResource$1.failed(BaseResource.java:130) ~[org.apache.pulsar-pulsar-client-admin-original-2.8.0.jar:2.8.0]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$1.failed(JerseyInvocation.java:882) ~[org.glassfish.jersey.core-jersey-client-2.34.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime.processFailure(ClientRuntime.java:247) ~[org.glassfish.jersey.core-jersey-client-2.34.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime.processFailure(ClientRuntime.java:242) ~[org.glassfish.jersey.core-jersey-client-2.34.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime.access$100(ClientRuntime.java:62) ~[org.glassfish.jersey.core-jersey-client-2.34.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime$2.lambda$failure$1(ClientRuntime.java:178) ~[org.glassfish.jersey.core-jersey-client-2.34.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:248) ~[org.glassfish.jersey.core-jersey-common-2.34.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:244) ~[org.glassfish.jersey.core-jersey-common-2.34.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:292) ~[org.glassfish.jersey.core-jersey-common-2.34.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:274) ~[org.glassfish.jersey.core-jersey-common-2.34.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:244) ~[org.glassfish.jersey.core-jersey-common-2.34.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:288) ~[org.glassfish.jersey.core-jersey-common-2.34.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime$2.failure(ClientRuntime.java:178) ~[org.glassfish.jersey.core-jersey-client-2.34.jar:?]
    at org.apache.pulsar.client.admin.internal.http.AsyncHttpConnector.lambda$apply$1(AsyncHttpConnector.java:204) ~[org.apache.pulsar-pulsar-client-admin-original-2.8.0.jar:2.8.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:859) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:837) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:506) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:2088) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.pulsar.client.admin.internal.http.AsyncHttpConnector.lambda$retryOperation$4(AsyncHttpConnector.java:247) ~[org.apache.pulsar-pulsar-client-admin-original-2.8.0.jar:2.8.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:859) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:837) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:506) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:2088) ~[?:?]
    at org.asynchttpclient.netty.NettyResponseFuture.abort(NettyResponseFuture.java:273) ~[org.asynchttpclient-async-http-client-2.12.1.jar:?]
    at org.asynchttpclient.netty.request.NettyRequestSender.abort(NettyRequestSender.java:473) ~[org.asynchttpclient-async-http-client-2.12.1.jar:?]
    at org.asynchttpclient.netty.handler.HttpHandler.readFailed(HttpHandler.java:161) ~[org.asynchttpclient-async-http-client-2.12.1.jar:?]
    at org.asynchttpclient.netty.handler.HttpHandler.handleRead(HttpHandler.java:154) ~[org.asynchttpclient-async-http-client-2.12.1.jar:?]
    at org.asynchttpclient.netty.handler.AsyncHttpClientHandler.channelRead(AsyncHttpClientHandler.java:78) ~[org.asynchttpclient-async-http-client-2.12.1.jar:?]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[io.netty-netty-transport-4.1.63.Final.jar:4.1.63.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[io.netty-netty-transport-4.1.63.Final.jar:4.1.63.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) ~[io.netty-netty-transport-4.1.63.Final.jar:4.1.63.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103) ~[io.netty-netty-codec-4.1.63.Final.jar:4.1.63.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[io.netty-netty-transport-4.1.63.Final.jar:4.1.63.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[io.netty-netty-transport-4.1.63.Final.jar:4.1.63.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) ~[io.netty-netty-transport-4.1.63.Final.jar:4.1.63.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:436) ~[io.netty-netty-transport-4.1.63.Final.jar:4.1.63.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:324) ~[io.netty-netty-codec-4.1.63.Final.jar:4.1.63.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:296) ~[io.netty-netty-codec-4.1.63.Final.jar:4.1.63.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:251) ~[io.netty-netty-transport-4.1.63.Final.jar:4.1.63.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[io.netty-netty-transport-4.1.63.Final.jar:4.1.63.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[io.netty-netty-transport-4.1.63.Final.jar:4.1.63.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) ~[io.netty-netty-transport-4.1.63.Final.jar:4.1.63.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410) ~[io.netty-netty-transport-4.1.63.Final.jar:4.1.63.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[io.netty-netty-transport-4.1.63.Final.jar:4.1.63.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[io.netty-netty-transport-4.1.63.Final.jar:4.1.63.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919) ~[io.netty-netty-transport-4.1.63.Final.jar:4.1.63.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166) ~[io.netty-netty-transport-4.1.63.Final.jar:4.1.63.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:719) ~[io.netty-netty-transport-4.1.63.Final.jar:4.1.63.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:655) ~[io.netty-netty-transport-4.1.63.Final.jar:4.1.63.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:581) ~[io.netty-netty-transport-4.1.63.Final.jar:4.1.63.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493) ~[io.netty-netty-transport-4.1.63.Final.jar:4.1.63.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989) ~[io.netty-netty-common-4.1.63.Final.jar:4.1.63.Final]
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[io.netty-netty-common-4.1.63.Final.jar:4.1.63.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[io.netty-netty-common-4.1.63.Final.jar:4.1.63.Final]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) ~[?:?]
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: org.apache.pulsar.client.admin.internal.http.AsyncHttpConnector$RetryException: Could not complete the operation. Number of retries has been exhausted. Failed reason: Maximum redirect reached: 5
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:331) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:346) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$OrApply.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:1503) ~[?:?]
    ... 39 more
Caused by: org.apache.pulsar.client.admin.internal.http.AsyncHttpConnector$RetryException: Could not complete the operation. Number of retries has been exhausted. Failed reason: Maximum redirect reached: 5
    at org.apache.pulsar.client.admin.internal.http.AsyncHttpConnector.lambda$retryOperation$4(AsyncHttpConnector.java:249) ~[org.apache.pulsar-pulsar-client-admin-original-2.8.0.jar:2.8.0]
```

UPDATE: made some tests pulsar 2.7.2 works without this issue, could not reproduce same exceptions.

Also while searching solutions found that for 2.8.0 need to change (Click [here](https://github.com/apache/pulsar/issues/3715%3E))

```
bookkeeperEnableStickyReads=false
```

but in 2.7.2 it is already false, but not sure if it is related some how.